# impossible to find the function "ggplot"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having problems with ggplot, getting the above error message.See full error message below after running library(ggplot2):

```
 Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 'vctrs' package 0.3.6 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.8 is required
Also: Warning message:
package 'ggplot2' was compiled with R 4.0.5
```

I have tried removing the package and then reinstalling it with dependencies. Nothing seems to work. The error seems to have been triggered when I tried to do an install of the ggflags package from Github, the package info states that it is a ggplot extension. Please give me an idea of how to fix this because I use ggplot for all data viz in R

Comment: Can you post your `sessionInfo()`? It seems you have some outdated `packages` and `dependencies`!

Comment: Looks like you need to update `vctrs`. For some reason it is not updating automatically. I see that happen for some core `tidyverse` background packages like `vctrs` and `rlang`. See if `install.packages("vctrs")` fixes it (or at least moves you to a new error!).

Comment: I ended up uninstalling R and R studio. After the reinstallation I got the following warning messages, see below:                                                                                             
                                                                                                                            
 Warning: the namespace 'ggplot2' is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing the 'gendergraph' object
Warning: the namespace 'scales' is not available and has been replaced by
by .GlobalEnv when processing the 'gendergraph' object

Answer (score 0):

Try the following shotgun-approach, as I suspect you are missing relevant `packages`,

```
# remove packages
remove.packages("tidyverse")

# reinstall
install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)
```

If this does not work, you should post your `sessionInfo()` in your post.